# The Laplacian in Polar Coordinates using the chain rule.

Tags: calculus

I have $f(x,y)$. Let $\newcommand{\t}{\theta}$ $x = r \cos \t$ and $y = r \sin\t$. I wan to write the laplacian equation

$$ f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0 $$

in polar coordinates.

#### Attempt:

First, using chain rule, we have

$$ f_r = f_x x_r + f_y y_r = f_x \cos \t + f_y \sin \t $$

and differentiate again we obtain

$$ f_{rr} = \cos \t ( f_{xx} x_r + f_{xy} y_r ) + \sin \t ( f_{yx} x_r + f_{yy} y_r ) = \cos^2 \t f_{xx} + \cos \t \sin \t f_{xy} + \sin \t \cos \t f_{yx} + \sin^2\t f_{yy}$$

And also

$$ f_{\t} = f_x \t_x + f_y\t_y = - r \sin \t f_x + r \cos \t f_y$$

So, using product rule, one has

$$ f_{\t \t} = -r \cos \t f_x - r \sin \theta ( f_{xx} \t_x + f_{yx} \t_y) - r \sin \t f_y + r \cos \t ( f_{yx} \t_x + f_{yy} \t_y) = -r \cos \t f_x + r^2 \sin^2 \t f_{xx} - r^2 \sin \t \cos \t f_{xy} - r \sin \t f_y + r^2 \sin^2 f_{yx} + r^2 \sin \t \cos \t f_{yy} $$

but, this looks really messy. Am I doing some computation wrong?

Comment: It can get a bit messy. Take a look at [this document](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/21C.w11/polar-lap.pdf).

Comment: FYI: There is a way of doing all of this quite cleanly - I'll write it up tonight if no one beats me to it.

Comment: (cont) But (fyi) the promised write-up might  be too general for your needs, so probably you shouldn't "wait" for it.

Comment: Using the same name for the function in cartesian coordinates and the (different) function in polar coordinates is a *Very Bad Idea* ${}^{\text{TM}}$.

Comment: Go to this [link](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/21C.w11/polar-lap.pdf) to see the way to handle polar coordinators.

Comment: @StackTD - this really, really is not a shameless request for +1 - but see "my" answer below for an alternative, non-messy approach to express the laplacian...

Comment: @xpaul - as I just wrote to StackD, this is not a request for +1, but see "my" answer for an alternative, general approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is, like, way overkill! I'm sure that you are better off with one of the links in the comment section.

Still, the following is, 'as promised,' a derivation of an expression for the Laplacian in terms of arbitrary orthogonal coordinates - and is worth documenting.

First of all, a whole lot of setup/notation, unfortunately:

Write $x = (x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in {\mathbb R}^n$. Suppose that $u_1,\cdots , u_n$ form an orthogonal system of coordinates on ${\mathbb R}^n$:

- by definition this means that if we write $x  = x (u_1,\cdots, u_n)$, then the vectors $${\partial x \over \partial u_k}= \left({\partial x_1 \over \partial u_k}, \cdots, {\partial x_n \over \partial u_k}  \right)$$ are orthogonal.

For instance, in your case, $x = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta )$. Then the pair
$$ {\partial x \over \partial r} = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta )\text { and } {\partial x \over \partial \theta} = (-r \sin \theta, r \cos \theta) $$
are orthogonal.

Write $h_k$ for the norm of the ${\partial x / \partial u_k}$, and set 
$$ e_k = {1\over h_k}{\partial x \over \partial u_k}.$$
The vectors $e_k$ form an orthonormal basis.

A nice property is that the  Jacobian  $\partial(x_1,\cdots, x_n) / \partial( u_1,\cdots, u_n)$ is the product of the $h_k$, up to sign, e.g., possibly after swapping coordinates $u_1$ and $u_2$: i.e., if we set 
$$ h = h_1\cdots h_n,$$
and write $ dx = dx_1\cdots dx_n$ and $du = du_1\cdots du_n$, then
$$ dx = \pm h \, du. $$
For neatness, assume that the sign is positive  - it won't matter.

If $f$ is a nice function on $\mathbb R^n $, write $\nabla f$ for its derivative or gradient:
$$ \nabla f = \left( {\partial f\over \partial x_1} , \cdots, {\partial f\over \partial x_n}\right).$$

- We wish to have an expression for $\nabla f$ in terms of $u_k$.

Since the $e_k$ are an orthogonal basis, we have that for any vector $v$,
$$v = \langle v, e_1\rangle e_1 + \cdots + \langle v, e_n\rangle e_n,$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the (usual) dot product. In particular,
$$\matrix{
\nabla f & = \langle \nabla f, e_1\rangle e_1 + \cdots + \langle \nabla f, e_n\rangle e_n \\  
 & = {1\over h_1}\left\langle \nabla f, {\partial x\over \partial u_1}\right\rangle e_1 + \cdots + {1\over h_n}\left\langle \nabla f, {\partial x\over \partial u_n}\right\rangle e_n.}$$
On the other hand, by definition,
$$ \left\langle \nabla f, {\partial x\over \partial u_k}\right\rangle = {\partial f\over \partial x_1} {\partial x_1\over \partial u_k} + \cdots + {\partial f\over \partial x_n} {\partial x_n\over \partial u_k}. $$ 
However, by the chain rule, the right hand side of the previous is $\partial f/\partial u_k$.
Therefore,

$$ \left\langle \nabla f, {\partial x\over \partial u_k}\right\rangle = {\partial f\over \partial u_k}.$$
So substituting in the above equation for the gradient, we get
$$ \nabla f = {1\over h_1}{\partial f\over \partial u_1} e_1 + \cdots +{1\over h_n}{\partial f\over \partial u_n}e_n, $$
which is already pretty interesting.

- We can now get to the desired expression for the Laplacian $\Delta f $, where, by definition 
  $$   \Delta f = {\partial^2 f\over \partial x_1^2} +\cdots + {\partial^2 f\over \partial x_n^2}.$$

The idea is to use, along with the above, integration by parts and "u"-substitution, using nice test functions $f$
 and $g$, which vanish for $x$ sufficiently large, so that the boundary values don't come into play: 
$$ \int \Delta f \, g \, dx = \sum \int {\partial^2 f\over \partial x_k^2} g \,dx  = - \sum \int {\partial f\over \partial x_k} {\partial g\over \partial x_k} \, dx =-\int \langle \nabla f, \nabla g\rangle\, dx.  $$
In the above, the integral is over all space.

Now write the above in terms of $u$. For the integrand, one has, from the preceding expression for the gradient, that

$$\langle \nabla f, \nabla g\rangle = 
 \left\langle 
\sum_k {1\over h_k}{\partial f\over \partial u_k} e_k,    
\sum_l {1\over h_l}{\partial g\over \partial u_l} e_l
\right\rangle.$$
But the $e_\cdot$ are orthonormal, so 
$$ \langle \nabla f, \nabla g\rangle = \sum_k  {1\over h_k^2}{\partial f\over \partial u_k}     
{\partial g\over \partial u_k} .$$

Therefore, combining this with repeated use of the chain and product rules for integration, one gets

$$
\matrix{ 
\int \Delta f \, g \, dx  &= -\int \,\sum_k {1\over h_k^2} {} {\partial f\over \partial u_k}     
{\partial g\over \partial u_k}\, h \, du \\ 
 & = \int \sum {\partial \over \partial u_k }\left( {h\over h^2_k}{\partial f\over\partial u_k}\right) g \, du \\
 & = \int {1\over h}\sum {\partial \over \partial u_k }\left( {h\over h^2_k}{\partial f\over\partial u_k}\right) g \, dx.\\ 
}
$$

*[ Here one sees that the absence of "$\pm$" in  $dx = h\,du$ is unimportant, as the sign would  have been canceled out above, anyway, on going back to the original parametrization.]*

Since $g$ is 'arbitrary', one gets the desired expression 
$$ \Delta f = {1\over h}\sum {\partial \over \partial u_k }\left( {h\over h^2_k}{\partial f\over \partial u_k}\right).$$

In your case,
$$ {\partial x \over \partial r} = 1 \, ( \cos \theta, \sin \theta ) \text{ and } {\partial x \over \partial \theta} = r\, ( -\sin \theta, \cos \theta),$$
so $h = 1\cdot r$. Hence 
$$\matrix{\Delta f &= {1\over r} \left \{ 
{\partial\over \partial r} \left( r {\partial f\over \partial r} \right)  
+ 
{\partial\over \partial \theta} \left( {r\over r^2} {\partial f\over \partial \theta} \right)
\right\} \\
&= {1\over r} \left \{ 
{\partial\over \partial r} \left( r {\partial f\over \partial r} \right)  
+ 
{1\over r} {\partial^2 f\over \partial \theta^2}
\right\}\\
&= {\partial^2 f\over \partial r^2} + {1\over  r} {\partial f\over \partial r} +{1\over r^2} {\partial^2 f\over \partial \theta^2}.
} $$

*[To give credit where credit is due, I learnt this argument from Sam Drury, quite a long time ago, now...]*

Comment: You got me coming back here anyway; (+1) for the nice answer.