# How do I compute $\Delta_x\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ when $x$ has arbitrary $n$ components?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I compute $\Delta_x\frac{1}{|x|}$ when $x$ has arbitrary $n$ components?

Is there any good way to simply this?

Comment: Is $\Delta_x$ some sort of derivative?

Comment: It is a laplacian operator, $\sum_i \partial_{ii}$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$

Comment: Where do you see the problem? If you know how to compute derivatives, this is straightforward (away from zero).

Comment: I'm wondering if I need a case argument in computation... I know this is basic but I somehow get 2 cases because when I differentiate $\frac 1{\sqrt{x-y}}$, with respect to $x_i$, I seem to have absolute value in the numerator, and the second derivative becomes more cumbersome... Given that the expression is very simple, maybe I feel that I'm missing something

Comment: As Michal says, depending on what you want, you can take a deep breath, and just do the calculus... If spherical coordinates are more convenient, you might take a look at 'my' answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044919/the-laplacian-in-polar-coordinates-using-the-chain-rule/2045926#2045926

Comment: @jk001 in your last comment, aren't you missing some squares? $$|x| = \left (x^2_1 + \cdots + x^2_n\right)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Ah yes! it should be $|x-y|$ instead of squre. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an exercise in computing partial derivatives. All you need to know is the chain rule and the product rule. Remember in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $$ \vert x-y \vert = \bigg ( \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-y_k)^2 \bigg )^{\frac 1 2}$$ where $x = (x_1, \dots , x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, \dots , y_n)$. Fix $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $$u(x) = \vert x - y \vert^{-1} = \bigg ( \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-y_k)^2 \bigg )^{-\frac 1 2}.$$ Via the chain rule, \begin{align*}
\frac \partial {\partial x_i} \vert x-y \vert &=\frac 1 2  \bigg ( \sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-y_k)^2 \bigg )^{-\frac 1 2} \cdot 2(x_i-y_i) \\
&= \frac{x_i-y_i}{\vert x-y \vert }. 
\end{align*} Hence, $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} = - \frac{1}{\vert x-y \vert^2} \cdot \frac \partial {\partial x_i} \vert x-y \vert = - \frac{x_i-y_i}{\vert x -y \vert^3}. $$ Now by the product rule, \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i^2} &= - \frac 1 {\vert x -y \vert^3}+3 \frac{x_i-y_i}{\vert x -y \vert^4}\frac \partial {\partial x_i} \vert x-y \vert \\
&= - \frac 1 {\vert x -y \vert^3}+3 \frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{\vert x -y \vert^5}.
\end{align*} Finally, \begin{align*}
\Delta u &= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i^2} \\
&= - \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1 {\vert x -y \vert^3}+3 \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(x_i-y_i)^2}{\vert x -y \vert^5} \\
&= -\frac n {\vert x -y \vert^3} +  \frac 3 {\vert x -y \vert^3} \\
&= - \frac {n-3} {\vert x -y \vert^3}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** after making the substitution $\boldsymbol r := \boldsymbol x - \boldsymbol y $, switch to [hyperspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere?oldformat=true#Polyspherical_coordinates) on $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$, for example using the following convention:
$$
\begin{split}
r_{1}&=\rho \cos \theta \prod_{j=1}^{n-2} \cos \varphi_{j} \\
r_{2}&=\rho \sin \theta \prod_{j=1}^{n-2} \cos \varphi_{j} \\
r_{k}&=\rho \sin \varphi_{k-2} \prod_{j=k-1}^{n-2} \cos \varphi_{j}, \quad 3 \leq k \leq n,
\end{split}
$$
with $r \in (0,\infty)$, $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$, and $\varphi_j \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Write the laplacian $\Delta_\boldsymbol r$ in these coordinates, then apply it to the *spherically-symmetric* function $(r,\theta,\dots)\mapsto 1/r$.